Sculpt mode - Paint tool removes viewport alpha/transparency?
In short, I want to trace over the edgeloops I painted for a model below some clothes. I start by adding viewport transparency to the coat (basically set Alpha to 0.5).
I do this using the Sculpt's "Paint" tool.
But, the moment I start painting, the clothes' viewport transparency disappears.

Why does this happen? Can I keep the coat's viewport alpha/transparency while doing Sculpt Painting?
(X-ray still adds back the transparency, so clearly it should be possible, right?)

